# 18.04 Avoid click and drag screen to access Desktop

Tags: .desktop, 18.04, wakeup

Fresh installation of 18.04
Wakeup system displays the time in the center of the screen.
Click and drag to top is needed to access the desktop.
I couldn't find how to avoid clicking and dragging, I want to just have the desktop displayed after moving the mouse or clicking a keyboard key.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open Ubuntu Software and install the GNOME Shell Extension called:

**Disable Screen Shield**

[image]
Source:
[Disable Screen Shield](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/672/disable-screen-shield/)

I want to take this moment to express the need for a consistent naming system. This "Screen Shield" has been called "Drag Screen", "Unlock Screen", "lock screen curtain", "phone style Gnome swipe" and so on. It would be much easier to find a solution to a buggy application if the application had a name (that you could find).

Bonus extra, disable screen lock after suspend by installing dconf-editor and navigating to org/gnome/desktop/screensaver and turn off ubuntu-lock-on-suspend. There's no way in the regular settings.

Comment: Does not work on Ubuntu 18.04.1. My 2c: UX really went down from 16.04... The screen shield swipe mechanism is making my desktop machine a phone! And let's not talk about all the annoying "simplifications" in nautilus... Arg!

Answer (score 3):

Just press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to access the username/password screen or you may like automatic login without any click.

Comment: How to avoid that? I want to have the desktop displayed after moving the mouse or clicking a keyboard key just once (same bahavior as 16.04), without having to click Enter. Screen Lock is set to off, no user/psw screen

Comment: What is your login manager? I guess it's GDM3.

Comment: Yes, it is the default one

Answer (score 0):

[heavily edited, was wrong about some assumptions]

Ok so the gnome team seem to have eventually realized that the screen shield *implementation* of GDM 3 is an abomination. (indeed it is absolutely atrocious, without any doubt whatsoever).

And have *started* working on a replacement. When that is finally ready, they will be able to retire the old screen shield. And any features of it would be re-implemented (presumably from scratch, we would hope). And integrated into the new login screen itself, as a single element.

So no more separate screen shield. Getting in the way, causing a nuisance.

The place to look at this new development work, while it is ongoing, seems to be over here:

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/issues/276

[edit 2]

Unfortunately the new design still seems to make the screen shield a mandatory part of the login screen. This is not actually what we wanted. A good place to complain about this would be at the link above ^ (login required). Or on alan's associated blog page / article about the new login screen design / proposal.

Until / unless they change their minds, then I can only recommend people try switching over to a different wayland compatible display manager. Researching the competition other than GDM3, only SDDM currently supports wayland too. Which is the login manager for KDE Plasma. So installing this on a stock version of ubuntu could mess up your installation. Due to all it's other KDE dependencies. Therefore a fresh install of kubuntu from scratch is safer. Try out the Kubuntu Live USB / ISO Disk Image before switching.

[how i reached this conclusion]

A breadcrumbs trail of prior gnome3 bugs leading up to it. Since the gnome3 developers say they are not planning to fix the existing / current / old screen shield included in 18.04 in the meantime...

These bugs are listed in a reverse order, from new to old:

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=720656

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=696330

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1049645